# Quickest way to obtain a repetitive query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enumerable

I need to use the following string as part of my query:

```
"(lower(first_name) LIKE lower(:first_param) AND lower(last_name) LIKE lower(:second_param)) OR (lower(first_name) LIKE lower(:second_param) AND lower(last_name) LIKE lower(:first_param))"
```

And it just doesn't feel right not to use some kind of enumerable method to generate it instead of putting it inside the code in the current form. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to use this query with more than two parameters?

Comment: No, it'll be used exactly as shown above.

Comment: Then what's wrong with using it as is? There's no point abstracting it if you are only going to use it this way. Wrap it in a scope on the appropriate model.

Answer (score 1):

Just Put the logic in the where clause like.

```
YourModel.where("(lower(first_name) LIKE lower(:first_param) AND lower(last_name) LIKE lower(:second_param)) OR (lower(first_name) LIKE lower(:second_param) AND lower(last_name) LIKE lower(:first_param))")
```

Comment: Well, I know what to do with it, I just wanted to generate this string in some tricky way but I guess it doesn't make too much sense :) I'm deleting the question

Comment: what are the dynamic property in this string.?

Answer (score 0):

Using a scope:

```
class User #or whatever
  scope :match_full_name, ->(first_name, last_name) do
    where("your query string", {:first_param => first_name, :second_param => last_name})
  end
end
```

usage:

```
User.match_full_name("john", "smith")
```